# AlertDialog lollipop cancel button black in dark theme

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-button

My application has a dark theme (`Theme.AppCompat`). When I try to add an `AlertDialog` my cancel button is black. This only happens on my Moto X on 5.0 (I've also tried the emulator on 5.1 and Samsung Galaxy S4 on 5.0). Here is a screenshot:

[image]

When my brightness is high you can see it better, but with my brightness low it is almost not visible. Does anybody have a clue how to solve this?

Code `AlertDialog` creation:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GigInfoActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Venue not added");
builder.setMessage("To mark this gig as favorite you have to add the venue. Do you want to add the venue?");
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, null);
builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null);
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably a bug on the Moto X with Android 5.0.

I now have Android 5.1 and it's working correct again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin.

https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

With it you can customize colors and other parameters, and is compatible with all android versions.

Comment: But I don't want to use a library for this. The system handles it perfectly, except the black cancel button on my Moto X.